# PHP sorting in descending order not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, group-by

I have the following table called :

**store_items**

```
id item_no   cat   sub
1  1l500bk   lady  sport
2  1l1550bk  lady  sport
3  2m1600rd  men   shoe
4  2m1599rd  men   shoe
5  2m1589rd  men   shoe
6  3l900bk   baby  shoe
7  3l1000bk  baby  shoe
```

As you can see the ***item_no*** contains numbers and text, when it comes to sorting I know it's painful. However, I've tried to test this PHP code :

```
//Table of results
$query = "SELECT * from store_items GROUP by cat,sub ORDER by cat,sub,item_no Desc";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(!$result){
    mysqli_error();
}

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo "<tr><td align=center>{$row['cat']}</td><td align=center>{$row['sub']}</td><td align=center>";

   echo ucfirst($row['item_no']);

   echo "</td></tr>";
}
```

All I want is to output list of cat and sub grouped together in which for each one of it will be listed next to it the newest/highest `item_no`...as follows :

Expecting output :

```
cat    sub    item_no
lady   sport  1l1550bk
men    shoe   2m1600rd
baby   shoe   3l1000bk
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is that `MAX(item_no)` does not correspond with `MAX(id)` for particular `cat` and `sub` values. The other problem is that `item_no` itself is alphanumeric and cannot determine naturally which one is the maximum. For that case you can first define your own function (because MySQL does not provide such) which allows you to convert `item_no` values to pure numeric strings (1l1550bk -> 11550):

Custom SQL function:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS STRIP_NON_DIGIT;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION STRIP_NON_DIGIT(input VARCHAR(255))
   RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
BEGIN
   DECLARE output   VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';
   DECLARE iterator INT          DEFAULT 1;
   DECLARE count INT DEFAULT 0;
   WHILE iterator < (LENGTH(input) + 1) AND count < 10 DO
      IF SUBSTRING(input, iterator, 1) IN ( '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' ) THEN
         SET output = CONCAT(output, SUBSTRING(input, iterator, 1));
         SET COUNT=COUNT+1;
      END IF;
      SET iterator = iterator + 1;
   END WHILE;
   RETURN output;
END
$$
DELIMITER $$
```

Then you can use this `STRIP_NON_DIGIT()` function to determine proper max `item_no` value for each `cat,sub` pair:

```
SELECT
    s.cat,
    s.sub,
    s.item_no
FROM
    store_items s,
    (
        SELECT MAX(CAST(STRIP_NON_DIGIT(item_no) AS UNSIGNED)) as numeric_item, cat, sub 
        FROM store_items 
        GROUP BY cat, sub
    ) t
WHERE
    CAST(STRIP_NON_DIGIT(s.item_no) AS UNSIGNED) = t.numeric_item
    AND s.cat = t.cat
    AND s.sub = t.sub;
```

This will give you desired output:

```
+------+-------+----------+
| cat  | sub   | item_no  |
+------+-------+----------+
| baby | shoe  | 3l1000bk |
| lady | sport | 1l1550bk |
| men  | shoe  | 2m1600rd |
+------+-------+----------+
3 rows in set
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks for reply, i'm going to understand and test what you have wrote. I'll inform you back with the results :) .. Thank again

Answer (score 0):

MySQL `MAX()` doesn't work on alphanumerical value.

If you don't have to many rows in your table, you can fetch all the data and do the job with full PHP.

If your table is too big, you should think about adding another field, like Gary Hayes says. You can use an autoincremental ID.

Comment: So I take that its not possible to do it , oh well I'll try now to edit the table structure.

Comment: @AliHamra you can do it. See my answer. If you want to change your table structure perhaps just add a "created_at" column.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really make sense to SELECT item_no if you aren't using it in GROUP BY or applying an aggregate function to it. You will randomly get one is the item_no values for reach row. You could `SELECT cat, sub, GROUP_CONCAT(item_no) as item_nos` instead.

```
SELECT cat, sub, SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(item_no ORDER BY id DESC),',',1) as newest_item_no
FROM store_items
GROUP BY cat, sub
ORDER BY cat,sub
```

Edit: I'm not sure what you mean by newest/highest item number, but my above query assumes that the highest ID is the newest item. Inside of GROUP_CONCAT you can change "id" to "item_no" if that is what you want to sort by. `GROUP_CONCAT` will get you a comma separated list of item_no in that order. The SUBSTRING_INDEX function then gets you only the 1st item_no in that lost and throws the rest away.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what I meant based on the expected output is that I need to find out the latest item number related to its category, because the item number always incremented each time I receive a new product. I've tried using your query but i'm getting `mysqli_error() expects 1 paramenter to be resource ...` . I'll double check whats wrong again

Comment: I fixed a couple errors in my query. 1 was I was missing the FROM clause. I highly recommend you try the query in MySQL ( eg in phpMyAdmin ) directly, before you try it in PHP, so you see any MySQL errors clearly. Your mysqli error is because of my query error, which causes a return value of Boolean FALSE instead of a result resource.